# Spring jms - rename the DLQ

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We're using spring jms with activeMQ and we want to rename the DLQ.
The reason behind this is that we have several projects, and we want each of them to have a separate DLQ.

So far I've only seen examples of how to set individual DLQs (for each queue).

Is it possible to simply rename the DLQ using the spring-jms xml configuration?

EDIT: From the comments I understand that there's no way to achieve this using spring. But maybe there's another way to change this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32330140/3166303

Comment: to my understanding, this solution also creates individual dlqs for each queue...and not a single 1 for each project

Answer (score 2):

The DLQ is not part of the JMS specification - it's completely in the domain of the JMS broker so, if the broker provides no mechanism to explicitly name a shared DLQ for a particular queue, there's nothing that can be done in Spring configuration.